# editing text file based on the content from other file via python

Tags: python, text, extract, filenames

I have some wav **files** under a directory, like this:

1. BAC009S0177W0368.wav
2. BAC009S0231W0262.wav
3. **BAC009S0517W0431.wav**
4. **BAC009S0002W0131.wav**
5. ...

Meanwhile, I have a text file:

1. BAC009S0002W0122|testing1
2. BAC009S0002W0123|testing2
3. **BAC009S0517W0431|testing3**
4. **BAC009S0002W0131|testing4**
5. ...

How can I create another **text file**, which containing content based on the **file name** of those **wav file** only via python, such as:

1. **BAC009S0517W0431|testing3**
2. **BAC009S0002W0131|testing4**
3. ...

Thanks @zwer
I am sorry forget post my trying code as well as. :(
Here it is:

```
import os

wav_path = "/home/user/wav_files" # wav files directory
txt_path = "/home/user/text_file" # BAC009S0002W0122|testing1
output_path = "/home/user/output_text_file"

standard = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(wav_path):
    for index, filename in enumerate(files):
        standard.append(filename[:-4])
# print(len(standard))
# print(standard)

test = []
with open(txt_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        parts = line.strip().split('|')
        test.append(parts[0])
        # print(test)

correct = set(standard) & set(test)
correct = list(correct)
# print(correct)
# print(len(correct))
# print(type(correct))
```

Right now, I could extract out the correct content line from the text file and save as list type only. :(

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @zwer I am sorry for forgetting posting my trying code as well as. :( I posted as bellow my original question already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in three easy steps - first list all `*.wav` files in a directory and strip their extensions, then iterate over the text file's lines and see if the string before the first `|` exists within the file list from the first step - if it does, write out the line in your out file, so:

```
import os

wav_path = "/home/user/wav_files"
txt_path = "/home/user/text_file"
output_path = "/home/user/output_text_file"

# get the *.wav files list, sans their extension; store in a set for fast lookup
wav_files = {f[:-4] for f in os.listdir(wav_path) if f[-4:] == ".wav" and os.path.isfile(f)}

# open the `txt_path` for reading and `output_path` for writing
with open(txt_path, "r") as f_in, open(output_path, "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:  # iterate the text file line by line
        if line.split("|", 1)[0] in wav_files:  # if present in the file list...
            f_out.write(line)  # write the line to the output file
```